# Isn't it mandatory to download google-services.json file after updating SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys in firebase.?

Tags: firebase, react-native, sha1, sha256

I am using `Firebase` for notification purpose and using `Google SSO` in my react-native app. `Google SSO` was working fine with debug and release apk generated from my machine. How ever it was not working in the app downloaded from playstore. Then I went to my `Play Console` account and copied SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys and added them in `Firebase`. Then `Google SSO` started working on `Playstore Version` as well. Even though I didn't download and update `google-services.json` file after updating the Playstore's SHA-1 and SHA-256, `Playstore` version is working good.

But when I updated Debug and Release key store's SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys, I had to download the updated `google-services.json`.

My doubt is, isn't it mandatory to download google-services.josn file after updating SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys in firebase.?